# vba excel get picture's bottom row

Tags: image, excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a picture. I don't know the size of the picture (it may vary).
I want to to get the last row of the picture in a variable (I want to leave a blank row to the bottom of the picture and start filling data in the next row). Could you help me figure out the syntax?

I can't even figure out how to get the picture into a variable..

I was able to do this with the following code:

```
 Dim testPic As Object
 For Each testPic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
    h = testPic.Height
    cellHeight = Cells(ImageTopRow, ImageLeftCol).Height
    nRows = h/cellHeight
 Next
```

But:
a. I don't need a foreach, there's only one picture in the collection, I just can't figure out how to get the first one.
b. There should be an easier way, right?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: asking for VBA code? => demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: @mehow: please see edits

Comment: ok see my answer, is this what you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim pic As Shape
Set pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)

MsgBox pic.BottomRightCell.Row
```

will show you the cell's location of the right bottom corner, ie

[image]

Comment: thx. I tried ActiveSheet.Pictures(1) and it didn't work, probably bacause I didn't use "set". Thx :)

Comment: They're objects so you need to use the `Set` keyword

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help.

"ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count " - this helps you count the number of pictures in the active sheet 
"ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)" - you can just use this if you only have 1 Photo or if you want the bottom right of the 1st photo

Code:

[click to view the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg0cH.jpg) Dim pic As Shape

```
Set pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count)

'Determines the address on the bottom right of the picture
lLast = pic.BottomRightCell.Address


'Selects the Bottom right cell of the Image/picture
Range(lLast).Select
```