# Can I select and print an image to PDF in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that creates a report which creates a table and a graph on sheet2. I then use the Excel camera function to paste an image of the combination table/graph on sheet1 below another range. (I do this because there are times the report image should not be visible.) The only help I can find is to print a range or an entire sheet. What I have tried is the code below.  But I know that `ExportAsFixedFormat`  is not a method for a shape or object. nor kind I find a method for printing a shape/object.  What I have tried - and does not obviously work - is this code. I may e able to do some gymnastics with getting a range, but being able to print the image would be a whole lot easier.  The image is named "Report". Any help is appreciated.

```
Set pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Report"))
strfile = " Projections" & "_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & ".pdf"
pic.Select

pic.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
  strfile, Quality:= _
  xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
  OpenAfterPublish:=Tru
```

Comment: Can you set the print area to the required range and PDF the sheet?

Comment: @Tim - Good ideas, but not easily.  The number of rows in the report can be dynamic. Worst case, I could just dynamically set the print area of the range where I copy the camera image on sheet2. It is not my preference, as it leaves me without some of the image formatting features I would like to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sleeping on it, I wondered if I could find the range occupied by the image.  And I found this thread that answered that.
[vba excel get picture's bottom row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327904/vba-excel-get-pictures-bottom-row)

The code that works is as follows"

```
Dim picRange As Range
Dim pdFile As String

    Set picRange = Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes("Report").TopLeftCell, ActiveSheet.Shapes("Report").BottomRightCell)
    strFile = "Dividend Projects as of " & "_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss") & ".pdf"
    pdFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & strFile
    
    picRange.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=pdFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```